Как указать разные поля для JOIN в зависимости от значения полей в основной таблице?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно указать разные поля для JOIN
в зависимости от значения полей в основной таблице?
SELECT par_1, par_2, par_3
FROM table_name_1
/*дальше нужна проверка:
Если par_1 is NULL, то JOIN table_name_2 on par_2 = par_2_2 and par_3 = par_3_3,
а если par_1 not is NULL, то JOIN table_name_2 on par_1 = par_1_1 */


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?

и ещё: вы указали метку sql. вам действительно ansi sql нужен?

"и ещё: вы указали метку sql. вам действительно ansi sql нужен?"  <- да, на работе использую sql

На голом SQL такого(вроде как) не сотворить. В table_name_1 много записей? Если вы хотите, что бы значения отбирались для каждого значения строки, то лучше использовать LEFT JOIN. Какая СУБД у вас?(mysql, MS SQL, Oracle, Postgree)

@aleksandrbarakin зачем подкалываете. Человек может искренне не знать про разновидности SQL. Стоит просто прямо спросить, какой кариант используется )

aleksandr barakin, простите, ввела вас в заблуждение

@aleksandrbarakin если человек не знает что бывают разные SQL, то врядли он сообразит что такое какой-то asni и причем он тут. Поэтому подколка конечно тонкая, но скорее потешит собственное эго, чем поможет вопросу. Простите )

Да влоб:
SELECT par_1, par_2, par_3
FROM table_name_1
JOIN table_name_2 ON (    (par_1 is NULL AND par_2 = par_2_2 and par_3 = par_3_3) 
                       OR (par_1 = par_1_1)
                     )
;

Только надо всем полям добавить алиасы таблиц.
Хотя разумнее два запроса и UNION ALL.
